# Ubuntu initial account can NOT log by public keys

Tags: openssh, ssh-keys, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to ssh logging from my Win10 client to Ubuntu server without annoying password input.

So I configure my Win10 client as this official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) said.

And here is my 2 accounts:

1.The initial account that I used when installed Ubuntu called `user_owner`

2.The another ordinary account that I created for others called `user_guest`

And I did paste my generated id_rsa.pub content from win10 client to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys file` of both of these 2 users on Ubuntu server.

Strange things happened:

1. It still requires password when I log from Win10 with

```
ssh user_owner@192.168.0.123
```

2. It just let me in without password with the same Win10 when log with

```
ssh user_guest@192.168.0.123
```

And I tried to edit my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on Ubuntu server

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

So please tell me why this happened and what I did wrong?

Comment: perhaps the owner/permissions are wrong in `/home/user_owner/.ssh` - or perhaps a typo in the name of the `authorized_keys` files - try `ssh -vvv user_owner@192.168.0.123` and check the output to see what is happening compared with `ssh -vvv user_guest@192.168.0.123`